# Alignment issue between BPMN.IO and Heatmap.js

Tags: heatmap, bpmn.io

I'm trying to overlay a bpmn flow using bpmn.io with a heatmap using heatmap.js. If the canvas is set to the first and only element in the dom it actually works, but once you add anything else like in my sample a header, the coordinate system between both gets off.

I've prepared a fiddle that shows exactly what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/rafaturtle/qt8Ly4ez/16/

```
  const rect = canvas.getGraphics(element).getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = (rect.x + rect.width / 2);
  const y = (rect.y + rect.height / 2);

  data.push({
    x: x.toFixed(0),
    y: y.toFixed(0),
    value: stats[element.id]
  });
```

I believe its on the calculation of x,y of each element, off setting it by a factor but after trying every combination I could think of I didn't manage.

thanks

Comment: did my answer help you to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I misunderstood what you aim for, but laying the heatmap over the elements can be easily achieved by using the dimensions of the current element, `element.x`, `element.y`, `element.width`, `element.height`.

The following code places the heatmap at the exact position of the elements:

```
var registry = bpmnJS.get('elementRegistry');
for (var i in registry.getAll()) {
  var element = registry.getAll()[i];
  if (stats[element.id] != null) {
    const centerx = element.x + (element.width / 2 )
    const centery = element.y + (element.height / 2 )
    data.push({
      x: centerx,
      y: centery,
      value: stats[element.id]
    });
  }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr8Lg53a/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const x = (rect.x + rect.width / 2) - canvas.getContainer().getBoundingClientRect().x;
    
const y = (rect.y + rect.height / 2) - canvas.getContainer().getBoundingClientRect().y;
```

try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ptbao/vjo4rxyp/3/)